# Excel: Sort one column into many column

Tags: excel

I would like to do the following data sorting/reshaping in excel. Is there a way to do this?

From this

> +--------+-------+
>   | Sample | Value |
>   +--------+-------+
>   |      1 |    30 |
>   |      1 |    10 |
>   |      2 |     6 |
>   |      2 |     5 |
>   |      3 |    62 |
>   |      3 |    20 |
>   +--------+-------+

To this

> +---------+---------+---------+
>   | Sample1 | Sample2 | Sample3 |
>   +---------+---------+---------+
>   |      30 |       6 |      62 |
>   |      10 |       5 |      20 |
>   +---------+---------+---------+

edit: please excuse my ugly table.

Answer (score 0):

If `30` is in B2, please try in C2:

```
=OFFSET($B2,2*(COLUMN()-3),0)
```

copied across and down to suit.